# Can I edit RcppExport.R by hand?

Tags: rcpp

I notice that there is a line that said
`# Generated by using Rcpp::compileAttributes() -> do not edit by hand`
in RcppExport.R.
But I wonder if there is the possibility that I could edit RcppExport.R by hand?
For example, I want to give a default value to one of my input a parameter.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a default value the standard way, again following what both languages involved permit (i.e. if you set one, all following args need one too per C++ rules):

```
> Rcpp::cppFunction("double mySum(double a, double b=10) { return a+b; }")
> mySum(4)
[1] 14
> mySum(4,5)
[1] 9
>
```

More generally speaking, and as this is your third somewhat basic Rcpp question in the space of 24 hours, could I suggest the [Introduction to Rcpp](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf) vignette, along with the other vignettes and maybe a look around the [Rcpp Gallery](https://gallery.rcpp.org) ?